# Как выставить слайдеру на @keyframes страницу для показа?

Tags: slider, css, keyframes, css-animation

```
 <div id="line">

       <img src="1.png" class="simg">
       <img src="2.png" class="simg">
       <img src="3.png" class="simg">
       <img src="4.png" class="simg">

 </div>
```

---

```
#line {
width:400%;
height:100%;
-webkit-animation: anime1 30s infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes anime1{
0% { margin-left:0px;}

20% { margin-left:0px; }

25% { margin-left:-25%; }

...

75% { margin-left:-75%; }

95% { margin-left:-75%; }

100% { margin-left:0px; }
}
```

Слайдер работает прекрасно. Однако появилась необходимость 'по юзерному велению' перематывать до конкретной страницы. Пытался:

```
document.getElementById('line').style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused"; //Останавливает, не перемещая вперёд, т.е. на месте
document.getElementById('linik').style.marginLeft = "-75% !important"; //0 реакции
```

Может вы что-нибудь подскажите?

Comment: У вас нет элемента с id="linik", а вы пытаетесь его получить? (последняя строчка кода)

Comment: Да там line должен быть. Просто в оригинале везде используется linik, т.к. line занят.